# SQL Select highest values from table on two (or more) columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

not sure if there's an elegant way to acheive this:

**Data**

```
ID   Ver   recID  (loads more columns of stuff)  
1     1       1  
2     2       1  
3     3       1  
4     1       2  
5     1       3  
6     2       3
```

So, we have ID as the Primary Key, the Ver as the version and recID as a record ID (an arbitary base ID to tie all the versions together).

So I'd like to `select` from the following data, rows 3, 4 and 6. i.e. the highest version for a given record ID.

Is there a way to do this with one SQL query? Or would I need to do a `SELECT DISTINCT` on the record ID, then a seperate query to get the highest value? Or pull the lot into the application and filter from there?

Comment: What database are you using?  The most general approach is to use row_number(), but this is not available on all DBS.

Comment: It's MS SQL server 2008, however I'd prefer something more agnostic ideally

Comment: As a caution, all the solutions that use a group by assume that there is only one vers per rec..  Is this the case?  Of duplicates, do you want multiple rows or just one?

Comment: There's should never be any duplicated "ver" per record ID, as this is incrimented in the application layer... Well that's the plan!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `GROUP BY` would be sufficient to get each maximum version for every `recID`.

```
SELECT  Ver = MAX(Ver), recID
FROM    YourTable
GROUP BY
        recID
```

If you also need the corresponding ID, you can wrap this into a subselect

```
SELECT  yt.*
FROM    Yourtable yt
        INNER JOIN (
          SELECT  Ver = MAX(Ver), recID
          FROM    YourTable
          GROUP BY
                  recID
        ) ytm ON ytm.Ver = yt.Ver AND ytm.recID = yt.RecID
```

or, depending on the SQL Server version you are using, use `ROW_NUMBER`

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
          SELECT  ID, Ver, recID
                  , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY recID ORDER BY Ver DESC)
          FROM    YourTable
        ) yt
WHERE   yt.rn = 1
```

Comment: This assumes that there is only one max per recid.

Comment: thank you, very speedy response and you just pipped Jason to the post for the answer!

Comment: @GordonLinoff - From the question (selecting "the highest version" for each recId) it seems that there is only one max.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - True for the none ROW_NUMBER version. Perhaps another reason to prefer ROW_NUMBER.

Comment: @dj18 Correct, I'm just after the highest "Ver" per distinct recID!

Answer (score 5):

Getting maximum `ver` for a given `recID` is easy. To get the `ID`, you need to join on a nested query that gets these maximums:

```
select ID, ver, recID from table x
inner join
    (select max(ver) as ver, recID
     from table
     group by recID) y
on x.ver = y.ver and x.recID = y.recID
```

Comment: this is the best answer as it's matching rest of the results in column to the highest value, thanks for that

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `cte` with `ROW_NUMBER` function:

```
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT ID, Ver, recID
    ,      ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY recID ORDER BY Ver DESC)as RowNum
    FROM data
)
SELECT ID,Ver,recID FROM cte
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

straighforward example using a subquery:

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tab a
WHERE   ver = (
            SELECT max(ver)
            FROM   tab b
            WHERE  b.recId = a.recId
        )
```

(Note: this assumes that the combination of (recId, ver) is unique. Typically there would be a primary key or unique constraint on those columns, in that order, and then that index can be used to optimize this query)

This works on almost all RDBMS-es, although the correlated subquery might not be handled very efficiently (depending on RDBMS). SHould work fine in MS SQL 2008 though.

Comment: Thank you, this is a great alternateive and I'll check which one is quicker for my needs and setup - a good alternative to the GROUP BY